# How to stop the bounce of UIScrollView at first and last index using UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, bounce

I have a UIViewController and I added UIPageViewController by programmatically. How to stop the bounce (scrolling) the UIViewController if we are at 0 index or last index? I mean bounce.

You can check this link: [How to create PageView with UITabBar or Segment Control using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852780/how-to-create-pageview-with-uitabbar-or-segment-control-using-swift)

And here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

fileprivate var pageViewController:UIPageViewController!
@IBOutlet weak var paginationView:UIView!
@IBOutlet var btnYourGroup: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnSharedBy: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var sliderViewLeadingConst: NSLayoutConstraint!

fileprivate var selectedIndex : Int? {
    didSet {
        var leading:CGFloat = 0
        if selectedIndex == 0 {
            leading = 0
        }
        else {
            leading = self.view.frame.size.width/2
        }

        self.sliderViewLeadingConst.constant = leading

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //SetUp Pagination
    setupPagination()

    for view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.delegate = self
            break
        }
    }

    //btnSharedBy.titleColor(for: UIControlState)
    btnSharedBy.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState())
}

private func setupPagination() {

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0)
    let vc = [startVC]
    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(vc, direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self
    self.pageViewController.view.frame.size = self.paginationView.frame.size
    self.paginationView.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
}

@IBAction func mainCateogryTapped(sender:UIButton) {
    loadNextController(index:sender.tag)
}

fileprivate func viewControllerAtIndex(index:Int) -> PageContentViewController {

    let feedsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
    feedsVC.pageIndex = index
    return feedsVC
}

fileprivate func loadNextController(index:Int) {

    if selectedIndex == index {
        return
    }

    let nextViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index:index)
    selectedIndex = index

    if index == 0 {
        btnSharedBy.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState())
        btnYourGroup.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
        self.pageViewController?.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if index == 1 {
        btnSharedBy.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
        btnYourGroup.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState())
        self.pageViewController?.setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else {

    }
  }
}
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as! PageContentViewController).pageIndex

    if index == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    index = index - 1
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index:index)

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as! PageContentViewController).pageIndex

    index = index + 1
    if index == 2 {
        //self.pageViewController.
        return nil
    }
    return viewControllerAtIndex(index:index)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {

    let vc : PageContentViewController = pendingViewControllers[0] as! PageContentViewController
    selectedIndex = vc.pageIndex
  }
}

extension ViewController : UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if completed {
        let vc = previousViewControllers.first as! PageContentViewController

        if 0 == vc.pageIndex {
            selectedIndex = 1
            btnSharedBy.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
            btnYourGroup.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState())

        }

        else {
            btnYourGroup.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
            btnSharedBy.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState())
            selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }

    else if !completed {
        let pageContentView = previousViewControllers[0] as! PageContentViewController;
        self.selectedIndex = pageContentView.pageIndex
    }
  }
}

//ScrollView Delegate
extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let point = scrollView.contentOffset
    var percentComplete: CGFloat
    percentComplete = fabs(point.x - view.frame.size.width)/view.frame.size.width
    //NSLog("percentComplete: %f", percentComplete)

        if(0.8 > percentComplete)
        {
            //selectedIndex = 1
            scrollView.bounces = false
        }

        else
        {
            scrollView.bounces = true

        }
    }
}
```

How can I stop bouncing problem at first and last index with button indicator also?

Comment: Why would you want to stop bounce from first and last index? How is this logical to you? The bouncing effect ONLY OCCURS on first and last index, thats what bouncing is.

Comment: My requirement is like I don't want to bounce.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798218/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bounce check here

Comment: I have tried this but not woking.
Thanks

Comment: "not woking" is maddeningly un-helpful. If you're looking for help, you need to be clear and descriptive about what your code is doing now, including user experience and any crash or error messages you get.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: This question looks like it was abandoned, with clarification requests going unreplied. I think it can be closed as "unclear" or no MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to walk the page view controller's subviews, looking for it's scroll view, and set bounces to false. This is a fragile solution however, and ill advised. (It's generally a bad idea to mess with a view controller's views, especially if there isn't a public interface to find them.)

The thread below has code that walks a page view controller's subviews and finds the scroll view. It would be easy to adapt that code to set the `bounces` property to false:

[Progress of UIPageViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577929/progress-of-uipageviewcontroller)

Comment: OK Thanks I will try this.
But it would better if you can see my code once and tell me where I have to change.
Thanks

Comment: Put the changes I suggested in viewDidLoad. I'm not going to write it for you. I found you a link to code that finds the scroll view. It should be simple to adapt that code to change the bounces property of the scroll view to false.

Comment: Ok I will check.
Thanks

Comment: If we press buttons and scroll the view, it fails. How can we stop please help.
Thanks

Comment: "It fails" is not at all helpful. Be specific about what happens, both from the user perspective, and what you see in Xcode, or there's no way we can help you. You also need to update your question to append your new code at the end.

Comment: I edited my code just now. In ScrollViewDelegate method I put the condition its working fine while scrolling  but when I press my buttons then scrollView bounce is becoming false.
Thanks